# Fast way to select rows within table in R?

Tags: sql, r, row, data.table, sqldf

I am looking for a fast way to extract a large number of rows from an even larger table. The top of my table is as follows:

```
> head(dbsnp)

      snp      gene distance
rs5   rs5     KRIT1        1
rs6   rs6   CYP51A1        1
rs7   rs7 LOC401387        1
rs8   rs8      CDK6        1
rs9   rs9      CDK6        1
rs10 rs10      CDK6        1
```

And the dimensions:

```
> dim(dbsnp)
[1] 11934948        3
```

I want to select the rows that have the rownames contained in a list:

```
> head(features)
[1] "rs1367830" "rs5915027" "rs2060113" "rs1594503" "rs1116848" "rs1835693"

> length(features)
[1] 915635
```

Not surprisingly, the straightforward way of doing this `temptable = dbsnp[features,]` takes *quite* a long time.

I've been looking into ways to do this through the sqldf package in R. I thought that that might be faster. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to select rows with certain rownames in SQL.

Thanks.

Comment: check out the `data.table` package.  you can do this using keys.  Are your "row names" identical to the `snp` column?

Comment: Yes, the two are the same. I'll look into data.table.

Comment: Just out of interest, does anyone know whether there's any time difference if you get the row numbers first with some mechanism like `foo<-rownames(dbsnp); bar<-which(foo%in%features,arr.ind=TRUE); temptable<-dbsnp[c(bar),] ` (I know that's not correct R syntax for which, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way most people would initially try it would be:

```
dbsnp[ rownames(dbsnp) %in% features, ]  # which is probably slower than your code
```

Because you say this is taking a long time, I suspect you have exceeded your RAM capacity and have started using virtual memory. You ought to shutdown your system and then restart with just R as a running application and see if you can avoid "going virtual".

Comment: I tried selecting the rows as you suggested it would 'usually' be done. It's much faster (I didn't realize you can do %in% from lists into lists).

Comment: From what you displayed, I think both of those objects were "atomic vectors" rather than R "lists". I admit to being a bit surprised that it was faster.

Comment: Cool - I'll keep that distinction in mind next time. I actually just learned the difference between the two from your post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594814/what-are-the-differences-between-r-vector-and-r-list-data-types

Answer (score 10):

The `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dbsnp <- structure(list(snp = c("rs5", "rs6", "rs7", "rs8", "rs9", "rs10"
), gene = c("KRIT1", "CYP51A1", "LOC401387", "CDK6", "CDK6", 
"CDK6"), distance = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("snp", 
"gene", "distance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("rs5", 
"rs6", "rs7", "rs8", "rs9", "rs10"))

DT <- data.table(dbsnp, key='snp')
features <- c('rs5', 'rs7', 'rs9')
DT[features]

   snp      gene distance
1: rs5     KRIT1        1
2: rs7 LOC401387        1
3: rs9      CDK6        1
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `sqldf` you will need `rownames = TRUE` then you can query on the rownames using `row_names`:

```
library(sqldf)

## input

test<-read.table(header=T,text="      snp      gene distance
rs5   rs5     KRIT1        1
rs6   rs6   CYP51A1        1
rs7   rs7 LOC401387        1
rs8   rs8      CDK6        1
rs9   rs9      CDK6        1
rs10 rs10      CDK6        1
")
features<-c("rs5","rs7","rs10")

## calculate

inVar <- toString(shQuote(features, type = "csh")) # 'rs5','rs7','rs10'

fn$sqldf("SELECT * FROM test t
          WHERE t.row_names IN ($inVar)"
           , row.names = TRUE)

## result
#      snp      gene distance
#rs5   rs5     KRIT1        1
#rs7   rs7 LOC401387        1
#rs10 rs10      CDK6        1
```

UPDATE: Alternately if `fet` is a data frame whose `features` column contains the required items to find:

```
fet <- data.frame(features)
sqldf("SELECT t.* FROM test t
          WHERE t.row_names IN (SELECT features FROM fet)"
           , row.names = TRUE)
```

Also if the data were sufficiently large we could speed it up using indexes.  See the [sqldf home page](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) for this and other details.