# Weird behaviour by ordering a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame that I want to order by the fifth column ("Distance").
When I try `

```
df.order <- df[order(df[, 5]), ]
```

I always get the following error message.

```
Error in order(df[, 5]) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'`
```

I don't know why R consider my data frame as a list. Running `is.data.frame(df)` returns `TRUE`. I have to admit that `is.list(df)` also returns `TRUE`. Is is possible to force my data frame to be only a data frame and not a list?
Thanks for your help.

```
structure(list(ID = list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
               Latitude = list(50.7368, 50.7368, 50.7368, 50.7369, 50.7369, 50.737, 50.737, 50.7371, 50.7371, 50.7371), 
               Longitude = list(6.0873, 6.0873, 6.0873, 6.0872, 6.0872, 6.0872, 6.0872, 6.0872, 6.0872, 6.0872), 
               Elevation = list(269.26, 268.99, 268.73, 268.69, 268.14, 267.87, 267.61, 267.31, 267.21, 267.02), 
               Distance = list(119.4396, 119.4396, 119.4396, 121.199, 121.199, 117.5658, 117.5658, 114.9003, 114.9003, 114.9003), 
               RxPower = list(-52.6695443922406, -52.269130891243, -52.9735258244422, -52.2116571930007, -51.7784534281727, -52.7703448813654, -51.6558862949081, -52.2892907635308, -51.8322993596551, -52.4971436682333)), 
          .Names = c("ID", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Elevation", "Distance", "RxPower"),
          row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What did you do to create such a data.frame? It's quite unusual.

Comment: @Roland I created the data frame using another function that output the single columns as list using lapply to avoid for loops. Maybe I should have solved it with sapply instead.

Comment: No, you should have used `do.call(cbind,...)` or something similar on the `lapply` output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your data frame contains lists, not vectors. You can convert this data frame to the "classical" format using `as.data.frame` and `unlist`:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, unlist))
```

Now, the new data frame could be sorted in the intended way:

```
df2[order(df2[, 5]), ]
```

Comment: I [thought](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594814/what-are-the-differences-between-r-vector-and-r-list-data-types) vectors and lists were the same

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Technically, they are not the same. Lists are a special type of vectors. Typically, the term "vector" refers to atomic vectors, i.e., vectors of "logical", "integer", "numeric", "complex", "character", or "raw" mode.

Comment: vectors also coerce data to a common type (i.e. if you have numeric and char elements everything will be char). list will keep the types correct so you want to stay away from vectors.

Answer (score 3):

I've illustrated with a small example what's the problem:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
          Latitude = c(50.7368, 50.7368, 50.7368, 50.7369), 
          Longitude = c(6.0873, 6.0873, 6.0873, 6.0872), 
          Elevation = c(269.26, 268.99, 268.73, 268.69), 
          Distance = c(119.4396, 119.4396, 119.4396, 121.199), 
          RxPower = c(-52.6695443922406, -52.269130891243, -52.9735258244422, 
                         -52.2116571930007)), 
          .Names = c("ID", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Elevation", "Distance", "RxPower"), 
          row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Notice that `list` only occurs once. And all the values are wrapped by `c(.)` and not `list(.)`. This is why doing `sapply(df, class)` on your data resulted in all columns having class `list`.

Now,

```
> sapply(df, classs)
#       ID  Latitude Longitude Elevation  Distance   RxPower 
# "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Now `order` works:

```
> df[order(df[,4]), ]  
#   ID Latitude Longitude Elevation Distance   RxPower
# 4  4  50.7369    6.0872    268.69 121.1990 -52.21166
# 3  3  50.7368    6.0873    268.73 119.4396 -52.97353
# 2  2  50.7368    6.0873    268.99 119.4396 -52.26913
# 1  1  50.7368    6.0873    269.26 119.4396 -52.66954
```

Comment: U're definitely right. I should convert all the columns of my data frame to vectors instead of list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This turns you data.frame of lists into a matrix:

```
mat <- sapply(df,unlist)
```

Now you can order it.

```
mat[order(mat[,5]),]
```

If all columns are of one type, e.g., numeric, a matrix often is preferable, because operations on matrices are faster than on data.frames. However, you can transform to a data.frame using `as.data.frame(mat)`.

Btw, a data.frame is a special kind of list and thus `is.list` returns `TRUE` for every data.frame.

Comment: Nice idea with the matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this same problem. This worked for me (maybe it might help someone else who is having the same problem and stumbled on this page).

I had a structure like:

```
lst <- list(row1 = list(col1="A",col2=1,col3="!"), row2 = list(col1="B",col2=2,col3="@"))
> lst
$row1
$row1$col1
[1] "A"

$row1$col2
[1] 1

$row1$col3
[1] "!"


$row2
$row2$col1
[1] "B"

$row2$col2
[1] 2

$row2$col3
[1] "@"
```

I was doing:

```
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst))
```

And I kept getting the same error you were getting when I tried to `df[order(df$col1),]`. Turns out I had to do:

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lst)
```