# R problem: Error in order(y): unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1' with function DFA of DFA.CANCOR package

Tags: r, list

Can somebody please explain what's going on here?

This is the code:

```
y <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
x1 <- c(4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 8, 7, 5, 3, 3)
x2 <- c(2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2)
discrim <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)
discrim$y <- as.factor(discrim$y)
head(discrim,3)
```

When I execute this code:

```
library(DFA.CANCOR)
DFA(data = discrim, 
    groups = 'y', 
    variables = c('x1','x2'),
    predictive = TRUE,
    priorprob = 'SIZES', # default is 'EQUAL'
    verbose = TRUE)
```

The following text appears:

*Error in order(y): unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'*
*Traceback:*

*1. DFA(data = discrim, groups = "y", variables = c("x1", "x2"),
.     predictive = TRUE, priorprob = "SIZES", verbose = TRUE)*

*2. squareTable(var1 = donnes[, 1], var2 = classes$dfa_class, grpnames,
.     tabdimnames = c("Original", "Predicted"))*

*3. factor(var2, labels = grpnames)*

*4. order(y)*

I have proved with unlist() the data frame like in [Weird behaviour by ordering a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521492/weird-behaviour-by-ordering-a-data-frame), but it does not work. I imported from a .csv instead of code by hand too, but does not work neither.

This is the example cited in the package documentation:

```
# data from Tabachnik & Fiddel (2019, p 307)
table9.1 <- '
1 87 5 31 6.4
1 97 7 36 8.3
1 112 9 42 7.2
2 102 16 45 7.0
2 85 10 38 7.6
2 76 9 32 6.2
3 120 12 30 8.4
3 85 8 28 6.3
3 99 9 27 8.2'
table9.1 <- data.frame(read.table(text=table9.1, col.names=c('group','perf','info','verbexp','age')))
DFA(data = table9.1,
groups = 'group',
variables = c('perf','info','verbexp','age'),
predictive = TRUE, priorprob = 'SIZES', covmat_type='within',verbose = TRUE)
```

.. and works nice ... my code, apparently, is very similar.
Please, help!

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I don't get any error when I run your code. Try to run your reprex in a new session with no other packages loaded. If that still fails, try updating your packages and R version.

Comment: Thank you for your response; I have updated the packages, as well as re-run in a new session and the problem persists; furthermore, I have uninstalled and re-installed both R and RStudio, but the problem persists in both as well as in Anaconda (with R kernel).

Comment: I noticed that I was still on version 0.2.2 of `DFA.CANCOR`. After updating the package, I also got the error. So it appears to be an error introduced in the latest version of the package. You can install the older version as a workaround. You should also contact the developer about the issue

Comment: Yes!!! Now, my code works well. Thank you very much **shs**; your help has been invaluable! I have posted an issue on the Github web of the developer. Thanks a lot again!