# Cycling through a vector

Tags: r, vector

I was wondering if it is possible in R to do it:

1. I have a `list <- c(x1, x2, x3, x4, xn...)`
2. With a for loop, put `x1` at the bottom of the list giving `c(x2, x3, x4, xn.. x1)`.
3. Next loop would be `c(x3, x4, x5... x1, x2)`

Is this possible in R?

Comment: You are confusing lists and vectors here.

But yes, it is possible - your best starting point may be to follow a very basic R tutorial... This may help for clearing the list/vector confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594814/what-are-the-differences-between-r-vector-and-r-list-data-types

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I'm gonna read this right now. Btw, if this exists, how could I do that?

Comment: Start here to learn about `for` loop syntax http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#for

Comment: See something like this: `vec <- c(5:10)` ; `for(i in seq_along(vec)) { print(c(vec[-(0:i)], vec[0:i])) }`.

Comment: @alexis_laz post it as an answer for the OP can upvote and accept it. It's what he's looking for.

Comment: As other's have pointed out in Answers, this can be done with some simple indexing or math, but I have such a function in my permute package (on CRAN) which does these cyclic shift permutations, and which will generate all such permutations for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but in the following example, you can "see" (`print`) what the loop does in each run:

```
#a vector (and not list)
vec <- c(5:10) 

#the loop
for(i in seq_along(vec)) { print(c(vec[-(0:i)], vec[0:i])) }

#[1]  6  7  8  9 10  5
#[1]  7  8  9 10  5  6
#[1]  8  9 10  5  6  7
#[1]  9 10  5  6  7  8
#[1] 10  5  6  7  8  9
#[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If you want to store the output and not just to see it, then consider this:

```
> result <- vector("list", length(vec))
> for(i in seq_along(vec)) { 
    result[[i]] <- c(vec[-(0:i)], vec[0:i])
  }
> 
> do.call(rbind, result)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    6    7    8    9   10    5
[2,]    7    8    9   10    5    6
[3,]    8    9   10    5    6    7
[4,]    9   10    5    6    7    8
[5,]   10    5    6    7    8    9
[6,]    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

In order to avoid pre-allocation in a list and the `for` loop and `rbind`ing at the end, `sapply` is good option

```
sapply(1:length(vec), function(i) c(vec[-(0:i)], vec[0:i]))
```

Comment: Thanks @Jilber for making it complete ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ditto. Not sure what you are trying to do but here's an alternative that returns a matrix...

```
sapply( 0:9 , function(x) c( (1 + x) : 10 , seq_len(x)  ) )
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10     1
# [3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    1     2
# [4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    1    2     3
# [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10    1    2    3     4
# [6,]    6    7    8    9   10    1    2    3    4     5
# [7,]    7    8    9   10    1    2    3    4    5     6
# [8,]    8    9   10    1    2    3    4    5    6     7
# [9,]    9   10    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     8
#[10,]   10    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
```

Comment: Another fun way is to do `n <- length(x); 
suppressWarnings(matrix(x, n+1, n)[-n-1,])`