# R: sum a 2D-list over 1 dimension

Tags: r, list

I have a two dimensional list called `mylist`.

I could access the dimensions like so:

`mylist[[a]][[b]]`
Where a ranges from 1 to 8 and b ranges from 1 to 4. All 8*4=32 entries are matrices of the same dimension.

I want to sum up all list over one dimension. Currently I use:

`mylist[[1]][[1]] + mylist[[2]][[1]] + mylist[[3]][[1]] + ... + mylist[[8]][[1]]`
`mylist[[1]][[2]] + mylist[[2]][[2]] + mylist[[3]][[2]] + ... + mylist[[8]][[2]]` 
`mylist[[1]][[3]] + mylist[[2]][[3]] + mylist[[3]][[3]] + ... + mylist[[8]][[3]]` 
`mylist[[1]][[4]] + mylist[[2]][[4]] + mylist[[3]][[4]] + ... + mylist[[8]][[4]]`

Is there a way to do that within one line of code? This is important for me now because the lengths become variable and are not restricted to 4 and 8 any more. I guess I need something like this:

`mylist_oneDimensional  <-  sum_list(mylist, dimension=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described as sum_list, it can be done like this

```
sum_list <- function(mylist, dimension=1){
  Reduce('+',lapply(1:length(mylist), function(i) mylist[[i]][[dimension]]))
}
```

For dimension = 1, calling sum_list(mylist, 1) will correspond to

```
mylist[[1]][[1]] + mylist[[2]][[1]] + mylist[[3]][[1]] + ... + mylist[[8]][[1]]
```

And sum_list(mylist, 2) to

```
mylist[[1]][[2]] + mylist[[2]][[2]] + mylist[[3]][[2]] + ... + mylist[[8]][[2]]
```

And so on depending in dimension value.

And then to get a list of all resulting sums, just use lapply again.

```
lapply(1:length(mylist[[1]]), function (i) sum_list(mylist, i))
```

This will only work correctly if `mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]], ...., mylist[[n]]` have same length.

Comment: Thank you very much romantsegelskyi. That was what I was looking for. I wonder I bit why that works since Reduce expects a VECTOR. But the output of lapply is a LIST.

Comment: @BerndMeyer Technically lists are vectors. More info in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594814/what-are-the-differences-between-r-vector-and-r-list-data-types.
Also, if the answer is good enough, please accept it :)