# Converting the row of a data.table to a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I want to turn `data.table` rows into vectors. Here's what worked for me:

```
unlist(dt[row_num])
```

But is there a more native solution? I also don't like that the above retains the name when really I want a pure numeric vector instead, which then leads to:

```
as.numeric(unlist(dt[row_num]))
```

Seems like there should be a better option.

Comment: that *is* the native solution for converting a `list` to `vector` in R; also note the `use.names` argument of `unlist`

Comment: You can also remove names with `unname`.

Comment: I agree with BondedDust's first sentence here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8595099/1191259 "Technically lists *are* vectors, although very few would use that term." In that sense, you can stop at `c(dt[row_num])`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem with extracting rows as vectors is that vectors are homogeneous while rows of data frames or data tables are not.

However, you can convert the data to a matrix then extract the row:

```
> x <- iris[1:10,1:4]
> as.matrix(x)[1,]
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
         5.1          3.5          1.4          0.2
```

Answer (score 17):

Ok, now I know you want a row:

```
as.matrix(dt[row_num])[1,]
```

IMO it is better to use first the `data.table`-operation and not to convert the complete datatable to a matrix. Simply the performance is better (especially on very large *data.tables*). Example:

```
library("data.table")
Iris <- data.table(iris[-5])
as.matrix(Iris[42])[1,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `melt.data.table()`, by specifying the row, along with the columns you want to extract (use `measure.vars = 1:ncol(iris.dt)` for the whole row). Select the values by adding `[, value]` on the end. It's best to specify columns that are all of the same type, or all the values will be converted to character (with a warning).

```
library("data.table")
iris.dt <- data.table(iris)

# One line solution:
row1 <- melt.data.table(iris.dt[1], measure.vars = 1:4)[, value]

# In steps:
iris.row1 <- iris.dt[1]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa

iris.melted <- melt.data.table(iris.row1, measure.vars = 1:4)
# variable  value
# 1: Sepal.Length    5.1
# 2:  Sepal.Width    3.5
# 3: Petal.Length    1.4
# 4:  Petal.Width    0.2

row1 <- iris.melted[, value]
# [1] "5.1"    "3.5"    "1.4"    "0.2"
```