# why does class function does not consider a vector as a vector in R?

Tags: r

I am learning this [post](https://www.statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html).

the author claim this is a vector

```
a <- c(1,2,5.3,6,-2,4) # numeric vector
```

but class function does not consider it is a vector

```
> class(a)
[1] "numeric"
```

for a matrix, everything goes well.

```
> a = matrix(1:6, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
> class(a)
[1] "matrix"
```

why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the basic types in R, like `numeric`, `character`, etc., are vectors. Even a single element like `3` is actually a vector of length 1. So `"numeric"` is implicitly a numeric vector.

Answer (score 2):

Your `a` object is a vector:

```
is.vector(a)
[1] TRUE
```

In R the term vector is much more general and many data objects that most mathematicians would think of as not a vector will also be considered such:

```
is.vector( list(a=2, b=3, list(d=4) ) )
[1] TRUE
```

See [a prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594814/what-are-the-differences-between-vector-and-list-data-types-in-r/8595099?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C33.5582#8595099) for what is considered a vector and not-vector. You can think of "vector" as a super-class. It's actually the presence or absence of attributes that switch from not-vector to vector status in R; in the case of R matrix objects it is the dimension attribute that causes the test to fail..

```
is.vector( matrix(1:4, 2,2) )
[1] FALSE
```

And there are some language objects that also qualify by the is.vector test:

```
 is.vector( expression(a,b) )
[1] TRUE
```