# Convert vector of vector to vector in r

Tags: r

```
x <- list(100, 200, 300)
> x
[[1]]
[1] 100

[[2]]
[1] 200

[[3]]
[1] 300
```

Is there a way to convert vector of vectors to a vector in r?

I am a newbie and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: Perhaps `unlist(x)`? FYI, the structure you're showing is a `list`, not a `vector`. (A vector will never show the `[[n]]` elements, just `[n]`. There are many other differences between them.)

Comment: @r2evans [lists _are_ vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8595099/6574038)

Comment: For most if not all new users, they are not the same, though the share many common things. Notable differences that are very important for new users: (1) all contents of a `vector` must be the same class, not true with `list`; and (2) math operations tend to work on vectors, not on lists. There are many other differences and some similarities, but for new users I tend to lean towards the simpler discussion of "different" for now. @jay.sf

Comment: Jay, does `unlist(x)` do what you need?

Comment: @r2evans Obviously OP comes from C++ or similar where this sort of structure is actually called a vector of vectors. You're right, that a list is a _generic_ vector in R, but the fact that a list is conceptually a vector of vectors can help OP avoid confusion.

Comment: @r2evans updated question with code if you want to answer! :-)